# Jenkins GitHub Webhook not triggering build

Tags: git, jenkins, github, jenkins-plugins, github-api

I see the webhook coming in the jenkinshost/log/all, it even "pokes" the job. And the job shows in the "GitHub Hook Log" that it just checked. But the commits don't match and it never starts the build.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally realized that even though the workspace is being cleaned up, it actually wasn't and it had the git checkout still present. I deleted the workspace manually on the server and the next commit push it started building. I think what happened is that it doesn't like force pushes, and I had done that. Figured I would put this out on the internet here as I couldn't find any other answers in my searches.